# Count number of words in a spark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How can we find the number of words in a column of a spark dataframe without using REPLACE() function of SQL ? Below is the code and input I am working with but the replace() function does not work.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
my_spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL example") \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()

parqFileName = 'gs://caserta-pyspark-eval/train.pqt'
tuesdayDF = my_spark.read.parquet(parqFileName)

tuesdayDF.createOrReplaceTempView("parquetFile")
tuesdaycrimes = spark.sql("SELECT LENGTH(Address) - LENGTH(REPLACE(Address, ' ', ''))+1 FROM parquetFile")

print(tuesdaycrimes.show())


+-------------------+--------------+--------------------+---------+----------+--------------+--------------------+-----------+---------+
|              Dates|      Category|            Descript|DayOfWeek|PdDistrict|    Resolution|             Address|          X|        Y|
+-------------------+--------------+--------------------+---------+----------+--------------+--------------------+-----------+---------+
|2015-05-14 03:53:00|      WARRANTS|      WARRANT ARREST|Wednesday|  NORTHERN|ARREST, BOOKED|  OAK ST / LAGUNA ST| -122.42589|37.774597|
|2015-05-14 03:53:00|OTHER OFFENSES|TRAFFIC VIOLATION...|Wednesday|  NORTHERN|ARREST, BOOKED|  OAK ST / LAGUNA ST| -122.42589|37.774597|
|2015-05-14 03:33:00|OTHER OFFENSES|TRAFFIC VIOLATION...|Wednesday|  NORTHERN|ARREST, BOOKED|VANNESS AV / GREE...| -122.42436|37.800415|
```

Comment: df.select("columnName").count() should be sufficient.

Comment: What is wrong with the `replace()` method?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan : that would give the total number of rows, not the number of words in the Address column for every row

Comment: @GordonLinoff : it gives out an error that it is an undefined function

Comment: can you give an reproducible example?

Comment: You would need to write a udf function for that. As @mtoto has suggested you need to update the question with input, what you've tried so far and expected output. Can you do that? If you do that I am sure that you would get dozens of answers immediately

Comment: @RameshMaharjan  just added some more info. thanks for the help

Comment: Is there a solution to the question using the format `spark.sql(SELECT FROM)`

Answer (score 43):

There are number of ways to count the words using pyspark DataFrame functions, depending on what it is you are looking for.

**Create Example Data**

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
data = [
    ("2015-05-14 03:53:00", "WARRANT ARREST"),
    ("2015-05-14 03:53:00", "TRAFFIC VIOLATION"),
    ("2015-05-14 03:33:00", "TRAFFIC VIOLATION")
]

df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(data, ["Dates", "Description"])
df.show()
```

In this example, we will count the words in the `Description` column.

**Count in each row**

If you wanted the count of words in the specified column for each row you can create a new column using `withColumn()` and do the following:

- Use [`pyspark.sql.functions.split()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.split) to break the string into a list
- Use [`pyspark.sql.functions.size()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.size) to count the length of the list

For example:

```python
df = df.withColumn('wordCount', f.size(f.split(f.col('Description'), ' ')))
df.show()
#+-------------------+-----------------+---------+
#|              Dates|      Description|wordCount|
#+-------------------+-----------------+---------+
#|2015-05-14 03:53:00|   WARRANT ARREST|        2|
#|2015-05-14 03:53:00|TRAFFIC VIOLATION|        2|
#|2015-05-14 03:33:00|TRAFFIC VIOLATION|        2|
#+-------------------+-----------------+---------+
```

**Sum word count over all rows**

If you wanted to count the total number of words in the column across the entire DataFrame, you can use [`pyspark.sql.functions.sum()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.sum):

```python
df.select(f.sum('wordCount')).collect() 
#[Row(sum(wordCount)=6)]
```

**Count occurrence of each word**

If you wanted the count of each word in the entire DataFrame, you can use `split()` and [`pyspark.sql.function.explode()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.explode) followed by a `groupBy` and `count()`.

```python
df.withColumn('word', f.explode(f.split(f.col('Description'), ' ')))\
    .groupBy('word')\
    .count()\
    .sort('count', ascending=False)\
    .show()
#+---------+-----+
#|     word|count|
#+---------+-----+
#|  TRAFFIC|    2|
#|VIOLATION|    2|
#|  WARRANT|    1|
#|   ARREST|    1|
#+---------+-----+
```

Comment: How can I use the count occurrence of each words code but incorporate stopwords?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it just using `split` and `size` of pyspark `API` functions (Below is example):-

```
sqlContext.createDataFrame([['this is a sample address'],['another address']])\
.select(F.size(F.split(F.col("_1"), " "))).show()

Below is Output:-
+------------------+
|size(split(_1,  ))|
+------------------+
|                 5|
|                 2|
+------------------+
```

Comment: Is F referring here to a dataframe?

Comment: F is as in `from pyspark.sql import functions as F`

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `udf` function as

```
def splitAndCountUdf(x):
    return len(x.split(" "))

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
countWords = F.udf(splitAndCountUdf, 'int')
```

and call it using `.withColumn` function as

```
tuesdayDF.withColumn("wordCount", countWords(tuesdayDF.address))
```

And if you want distinct count of words, you can change the `udf` function to include `set` as

```
def splitAndCountUdf(x):
    return len(set(x.split(" ")))

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
countWords = F.udf(splitAndCountUdf, 'int')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Spark SQL

```sql
SELECT word, count(*)
FROM
    (SELECT explode(split(Description, ' ')) AS word FROM mytable)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Full example

```py
data = [
    ("2015-05-14 03:53:00", "WARRANT ARREST"),
    ("2015-05-14 03:53:00", "TRAFFIC VIOLATION"),
    ("2015-05-14 03:33:00", "TRAFFIC VIOLATION")
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["Dates", "Description"])
df.createOrReplaceTempView("mytable")

spark.sql("""
    SELECT word, count(*)
    FROM
        (SELECT explode(split(Description, ' ')) AS word FROM mytable)
    GROUP BY 1
    ORDER BY 2 DESC
""").show()
```