# Spark - How to word count without RDD

Tags: apache-spark

It looks RDD is to be removed from Spark.

[Announcement: DataFrame-based API is primary API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.6/ml-guide.html#announcement-dataframe-based-api-is-primary-api)

> The RDD-based API is expected to be removed in Spark 3.0

Then, how to implement programs like word count in Spark?

Comment: Dataframes still have grouping operations.

Answer (score 1):

The data you manipulate as tuples using RDD api can be thought of and manipulated as columns/fields in a SQL like manner using DataFrame api.

```scala
df.withColumn("word", explode(split(col("lines"), " ")))
  .groupBy("word")
  .count()
  .orderBy(col("count").desc())
  .show()
```

```
+---------+-----+
|     word|count|
+---------+-----+
|      foo|    5|
|      bar|    2|
|     toto|    1|
...
+---------+-----+
```

Notes:

- This code snippet requires necessary imports from `org.apache.spark.sql.functions`
- Relevant examples can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48927271/count-number-of-words-in-a-spark-dataframe/48930628)'s answers.